# Hide products from WooCommerce archives assigned to some categories, but not as related product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to hide a category (I actually need to hide two categories) from all the WooCommerce shop listing pages, category pages, and site search? But show the products in these two categories when they're assigned as a related product?

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does mean "Hide a Category of Products from Listing Pages and Site Search, but Show As Related Product"… Do you mean hiding products that are assigned to that categories, or hide the category terms? Try to be more explicit. If you tried something (some code) even if it doesn't work, it's recommended to add it in your question, if you want to have better chances to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry. I mean hide all the products that are assigned to two specific categories from all the listing and search pages. But show them as related products (when linked to other products in the store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, where you will replace in `array('tshirts','hoodies'),` by your desired product category slugs:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only in frontend
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('tshirts','hoodies'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

It will not affect related products.